# imwrite merged image : writing image after adding alpha channel to it opencv python

Tags: image, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I want to change background of image and add alpha channel to it before saving it as a png file.

`imshow` shows the image , but `imwrite` writes an empty image. 
Dimension after merging is also correct, i.e. the merged image has `(x,y,4)` when I print `img_a.shape`

The image depth is `uint8`. I tried changing it to `float32` and then divide by `255` but nothing seem to work. I am missing something basic.

What should I do so that `imwrite` writes the correct png with alpha channel ?
I tried `cv2.merge` and `np.dstack`. `imwrite` fails to write. 
On opening it with gimp, it shows one layer.

Following is my code.

```
imgo = cv2.imread('PCP_1.jpg')
image = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgo, (5, 5), 0)
r = image.shape[0]
c = image.shape[1]
shp = (r,c,1)
c_red, c_green, c_blue = cv2.split(image)
#c_red = c_red.astype(np.float32)
#c_green =c_green.astype(np.float32)
#c_blue = c_blue.astype(np.float32)
alphachn = np.zeros(shp)
#alphachn = alphachn.astype(np.float32)
img_a = cv2.merge((c_red, c_green, c_blue, alphachn))
#img_a = np.dstack( (imgo, np.zeros(shp).astype(np.uint8) ) )
print img_a.shape
cv2.imshow('image', img_a)
cv2.imwrite('image_alpha.png', img_a)
k = cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with your alpha channel, The reason why the image is shown in `imshow` but not shown with `imwerite` lies in the face that *cv2.imshow() rejects the alpha channel whereas imwrite takes into account the alpha channel.*

As per your code you are defining the alpha channel as `alphachn = np.zeros(shp)` which created a numpy matrix filled with zeros, and an alpha channel with all zero value means **Transparent** image, Or in other words if the alpha channel is zero then the RGB value for that pixel is never visible, This is the reason you are getting an empty image with `imwrite()`.

For a fix you should initialize the alpha as `alphachn = np.ones(shp, dtype=np.uint8)*255` which created a numpy matrix with `255` values filled in it. If you want to tweak the alpha channel value to get semi-transparent results then you may use 150 insted of 255.

Comment: I did alphachn = np.ones(shp)*255 and then alphachn.astype('uint8') before merging. imwrite has successfully written the image. Thank you !